# Python IRC bot + SQLAlchemy - track users in multiple channels

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, twisted, irc

I'm currently storing IRC users in a dictionary, using their nickname as the 'key' for easy retrieval. The users are retrieved from SQLAlchemy, so `users['deepy']` is an SQLAlchemy object which I regularly sync with my database.

Now the problem I have is that on IRC, people can be in many channels and I'm just keeping track of one. I need a suggestion on how to improve this.

I've been thinking about doing pretty much the same, but also storing the channel's users (as a list) in a dictionary with the channel names as key, so like:

`{  '#two': ['reference to user9', 'reference to user62'], '#one': ['reference to user1', 'reference to user2']  }`

The references being to the users dictionary which contains the SQLAlchemy object.

Is that a sensible approach?

I am using Python 2.7, [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), [SQLAlchemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy) and Twisted's irc.ircclient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it's best to store as few SQLALchemy objects as possible. Storing a ton of SQLAlchemy objects leads to having to worry about synchronization issues and uses up memory.

I would keep track of usernames or user ids instead of actual user objects:

```
{ '#two': ['bob1', 'tom2'], '#one': ['bob1', 'mary1'] }
```

Then whenever I needed information for a user I would fetch them from the database. If I had only a few users and needed to access them frequently then I would create a dictionary that mapped usernames to SQLAlchemy user objects.